# 'Where I should be' vs 'The place I should be'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which of these is correct:

> 1. Where I should be.

or

> 2. The place I should be.

?

---

Context: When you are going to fill the autobiography section on SE, it says 'Location' and it's supposed to write USA or something like that and I wanted to write one of the 2 above.

---

What are other alternative ways to mean the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, "Where I should be" is the clause functioning like "the place in/at/etc which I should be", or "the place I should be in/at/etc.". E.g *I don't know where I should be.* ; *Where should I be?*

"Where I should be." is fine as a joke in that context. I think.

Comment: But you're not answering the question. Is it correct to fill "Location" with just "Where I should be" as a kind of joke?

Comment: @RubioRic I didn't know Op has updated his question.

Comment: +1 Sorry, I didn't see the edit history.

Comment: @RubioRic: the only thing I edited was the _context_, my question has been always there

Comment: What do you mean with as a joke?

Comment: @Isa It's because as you said "it says 'Location' and it's supposed to write USA or something like that", but instead you write something else like "where I should be".

Comment: @Isa "Location" is supposed to contain an specific geographical location. I live in Málaga (Spain) not "where my heart belongs" or "where I should be" or "I'm not gonna tell you" or whatever that you may choose to introduce in that field. I guessed that it was some kind of joke

Answer (score 0):

"where should i be" and "the place i should be", virtually mean the same thing. There is really no other way you need to put it unless there is a context.

Answer (score 0):

> What are other alternative ways to mean the same?

Another way is:

> > Where I meant to be